# testing pygtk in Xvfb

Tags: python, unit-testing, pygtk

I want to test my code in a temporary framebuffer display.

It works, except when the `gtk` module gets loaded before setting up the Xvfb and updating `os.environ['DISPLAY']`.

In our test suite, I can't modify the order of the tests, and that's why `gtk` gets imported before `setUp()` of my `TestCase` gets run.

Unloading modules does not work in python ....

Any chance to solve this?

Using `subprocess` is not a solution, since this would cause coverage to not see the execution of the tests...

Again: setting up Xvfb and testing works, but gtk must no be loaded too early.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to reinitialize `gtk` with the new `DISPLAY` environment variable.

I use this now: set up `xvfb` in the `TestCase`, and the `test_method()` uses `subprocess` to run the test code.

Related: http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2014-May/020750.html (up to now no answer)